# Amazon SNS does not sending SMS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried both AWS cli and SNS console and it does not work at all. 
However, I pushed to email is worked well but not for SMS.

In cloudwatch, it said `providerResponse": "Internal error"`

My region is ap-southeast-2

I tried to push SMS to Thailand (+66)

Answer (score 0):

During the SMS testing on the Aws sns we did find the same behavior.
It can be partly because SNS has a dependency on the service provider and SMS termination gateway.We did setup backup service with twilio to send out SMS.Found twilio SMS to be pretty more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your replying, however, I plan to use verify api from Twilio, but it does not allow me to change a sendeer ID called "Authy" to be my brand at all. How can I change it?

Comment: Again the specific sender id was implemented to ensure the service providers don't block the sms https://support.authy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009533114-AUTHMSG-for-Verify-and-Authy

Comment: Thanks again! Sender ID is not parameter in phone verification API. Should I create my own OTP?

Comment: No Authy service generates the OTP